# Get content versionned file in groovy GitBlit hook

Tags: git, groovy, hook, gitblit

I have a custom pre-receive hook GitBlit made in Groovy. I would like to read a versionned file in the current repository and extract its content in a string.

I already saw `{repository}` and `{user}` vars to get the absolute path of the repository, but nothing found.

Do you know any parameter or tool function to get path (or content) of this file ?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution consulting this [page](https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?class=com.gitblit.utils.StringUtils&method=getSHA1). There is tools functions in `com.gitblit.utils.JGitUtils` and `com.gitblit.GitBlit` who allow to get file content as a string.

Documentation is available [here](https://github.com/gitblit/gitblit/blob/master/src/main/java/com/gitblit/utils/JGitUtils.java)

```
import com.gitblit.GitBlit
import com.gitblit.Keys
import com.gitblit.models.RepositoryModel
import com.gitblit.models.UserModel
import com.gitblit.utils.JGitUtils
import org.eclipse.jgit.lib.Repository
import org.eclipse.jgit.revwalk.RevCommit
import org.eclipse.jgit.transport.ReceiveCommand
import org.eclipse.jgit.transport.ReceiveCommand.Result
import org.slf4j.Logger

// Get repository
def repo = gitblit.getRepository(repository.name)
//logger.info(repo.dump()) // See a dump of the var in the logs

// Get string file content
def str = JGitUtils.getStringContent(repo, null, "myFile.txt", null)
```

> NB : `repository` var is naturally injected by GitBlit at the
>   execution of the groovy hook script.